# Binding to a service from a library

Tags: android, service, bind

I have a sample which I bind to a service and this one works. When I try to move the code that binds to the service to a library the call to BindService fails with exception. Any idea or a sample code I can take a look at?

This is the bind call:

```
boolean rc = bindService(MyIntent, mConnectionC, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This is the exception log:

```
04-02 17:28:36.896: W/System.err(1567): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 17:28:36.947: W/System.err(1567):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:337)
04-02 17:28:36.976: W/System.err(1567):     at com.Locification.LocificationToolKit.InitLocification(LocificationToolKit.java:280)
04-02 17:28:36.996: W/System.err(1567):     at com.LocificationClient.LocificationClientActivity.onCreate(LocificationClientActivity.java:49)
04-02 17:28:37.026: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-02 17:28:37.046: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-02 17:28:37.086: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-02 17:28:37.106: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-02 17:28:37.126: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-02 17:28:37.156: W/System.err(1567):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-02 17:28:37.186: W/System.err(1567):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-02 17:28:37.207: W/System.err(1567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-02 17:28:37.236: W/System.err(1567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 17:28:37.256: W/System.err(1567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-02 17:28:37.286: W/System.err(1567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-02 17:28:37.356: W/System.err(1567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-02 17:28:37.386: W/System.err(1567):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please tag the question with target platform (windows?)

Comment: The code is running on Android

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an equivalent context to bind? I recall that bind behavior depends on whether you call `bindService()` for an activity vs. receiver vs. service context.

And also: what exception? Any "caused by"?

EDIT: NullPointerException typically means that you've passed a null where a valid object was expected. Moreover, the exception took place within ContextWrapper - most methods in there do nothing but pass the call to the underlying context object. Which hints that the base context was not initialized properly.

I see the call takes place within class `LocificationToolKit`. Is `LocificationClientActivity` a subclass of `LocificationToolKit`? If not, are you calling the constructor of `LocificationToolKit` properly with a `Context` parameter? It really looks like you're trying to bind to a service from within a `ContextWrapper` that has not been initialized with a non-null base context.

EDIT2: `InitLocification()` cannot be a static method - 'cause then you won't be able to call `bindService()` from it. Therefore, you have a `LocificationToolKit` instance somewhere, initialized somewhat like this:

```
LocificationToolKit LoTo = new LocificationToolKit(/*...*/);
```

So what you need is a constructor in LocificationToolKit, which takes a `Context` object and passes it to the base class:

```
LocificationToolKit(Context c)
{
    super(c);
}
```

And when you construct your `LocificationToolKit` somewhere in `LocificationClientActivity`, you need to pass the activity's `this` pointer as a context. Like this:

```
LocificationClientActivity
{
    void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        //...
        LocificationToolKit LoTo = new LocificationToolKit(this);
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the call: boolean rc = bindService(MyIntent, mConnectionC, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

Comment: I am binding from a class that extends Activity (but is a library - no apk) to a class that extends Service. Not sure to which this you refer.

Comment: OK, an activity context should fly. Now let's take a look at the exception. Don't paste as comment, edit the main question instead.

Comment: The toolkit class is a service class that should provide the interface for the client to the service. Looks like I need to construct the class with the right context... not sure how yet...

Comment: What is the base class of `LocificationToolKit`? Also, seems like you need to read up on the basics of Java.

Comment: OK, does `LocificationClientActivity` extend `LocificationToolKit`?

Comment: no, each of them extends Activity. The toolkit is used as a library for LocificationClientActivity, hence, it does not have a looper.

Comment: How is LocificationToolKit instantiated, then? Does it have a constructor? What's it like? What does it pass to the `super` constructor? Do you know what's a constructor?

Comment: I know - I have a lot of experience with C++. I am trying to generate something equivalent to a .lib of a service class. As for the constructor, I use the defaults. I didn't implement my own constructor (other than the one you have proposed with context, but fails to call super(context)).

Comment: Eventually I have just added my code as 2 classes, archived them in a JAR file and added the JAR as External JAR to the project.